# Как сделать, чтобы при вызове функции openbox масонри пересчитывался, как при ресайзе экрана?

Tags: javascript

Есть два скрипта:

1. По клику скрывает и отображает лишние блоки, а основной блок делает то на всю ширину экрана, то на 50% соответственно.
2. Скрипт плагина Масонри.

Как сделать, чтобы при вызове функции openbox масонри пересчитывался, как при ресайзе экрана?

Условно говоря, делаю кнопку fullscreen, но масонри не пересчитывает. Как правильно сделать?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function openbox(id){
    display = document.getElementById('b3').style.width;

    if(display=='50%'){
        document.getElementById('b1').style.visibility='collapse';
        document.getElementById('b2').style.visibility='collapse';
        document.getElementById('b3').style.width='100%';
        document.getElementById('b4').style.visibility='collapse';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('b1').style.visibility='visible';
        document.getElementById('b2').style.visibility='visible';
        document.getElementById('b3').style.width='50%';
        document.getElementById('b4').style.visibility='visible';
    }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#container').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.item',
          singleMode: false,
        }); 
});
</script>
```

---

Вопрос из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/486798/6) [@user200316](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/200316/user200316).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

прочитать документацию [здесь](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html) и добавить запуск метода layout после изменения ширины, пример на jquery ниже счёлкните левый или правый блок пару раз не спеша.

```js
  $(function() {
    var $container = $(".block_info");

    function more() {
      $.each(Array(Math.round(Math.random() * 20 + 11)), function(indx, element) {
        $('<img/>', {
          'src': 'http://tympanus.net/Development/AutomaticImageMontage/images/' + (Math.round(Math.random() * 72 + 1)) + '.jpg'
        }).prependTo($container[indx % 2])
      });


    }
    more()
    var $container = $('.block_info');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: 'img',
        "gutter": 10
      });
      $container.on({
        click: function() {
          var i = +$container.not(this).toggle().is(':hidden');
          $(this).css({
            width: i ? "100%" : "45%"
          })
          $container.masonry('layout');
        }
      })
    });
  });
```

```css
    .block_info {
      width: 45%;
      border: 4px solid #0000FF;
      float: left;
      margin: 5px;
      text-align: center;
      height: auto;
    }
    img {
      width: 125px;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/3.2.2/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.js"></script>
<div class='block_info'></div>
<div class='block_info'></div>
```